# Django doesn't add me content into sqlite db

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, object

im parsing an XML doc, adding into sqlite db and same time printing it in console. I've different fields. For example, I've in my db, TITULO, charField(max_length=100).

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Actividad(models.Model):
    id_evento = models.FloatField()
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

TITUTO field works OK
..

```
    elif self.TITULO:
        self.Evento.titulo = content
```

now, do the same with another field called TIPO

```
    elif self.TIPO:
        self.Evento.tipo = content
```

does nothing! It is printed in console, but not added into sqlite db, same field charField(max_length=100), there is no msg error!

Im doing print(content) and can see it in the screen, but no in the sqlite db! I mean, I can see the content printed in the screen, but it doesn't update in the db and there is TIPO blank field.

(At least I do self.Evento.save())

EDIT:

```
    elif self.TIPO:
        self.Evento.tipo = "hola"
        print self.Evento.tipo
```

I've changed my code like that.
It prints "hola", but it doesn't saved it into the db!

Comment: Missing information: what are these two fields? (What are your models?) Also, don't make claims like "I'm printing it in console and I can see it!" Paste it here! Let us see what you are looking at.

Comment: sorry,  

from django.db import models

class Actividad(models.Model):
    id_evento = models.FloatField()
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Comment: Please paste into your question rather than a comment. :)

Comment: Are you sure the code in `elif self.TIPO:` is executed ?

Comment: yes, this is why I wrote "print(content)"

Comment: now, I wrote "print("hello")" for making me sure that the code inside elif is executed. Yes, it is. And wrote too "self.Evento.tipo = "hola""
but doesn't matter

Comment: how and where do you use save()?

Comment: then, and self.Evento.titulo is working ok. 
I wanna paste the entire code, but its too much code because its inside the XMLparser too. mh.. how can I send or upload it somewhere?

Comment: @dmanso try http://pastebin.com/